# How to show html ng-repeat inside tooltip

Tags: angularjs, html-table, angularjs-ng-repeat, tooltip

I'm using angularjs so I added a directive in my app.

```
app.directive('tooltip', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            $(element)
                .attr('title', scope.$eval(attrs.tooltip))
                .tooltip({ placement: "right" });
        }
    }
})
```

I want to display the html below or something similar to it, I just want to show a list of customers in the `tooltip`

```
<ol>
    <li ng-repeat='dt in detail.SelectedCustomers'>{{dt.name}}</li>
</ol>
```

Below is my table where the `tooltip` is located.

```
<tr ng-repeat="detail in mainCtrl.lineDetails">
    <td><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-html="true" tooltip="detail.SelectedCustomers"><i class="fa fa-eye fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: not quite sure but I think native tooltip won't be enough to display a list like you want. You can use a third-party library that helps you do that with custom tooltips/popovers. probably [angular-ui](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)?

Comment: Can you please share mainCtrl.lineDetails value? It will more helpful to you. What type of content do you want to display in the tooltip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yvbenitah/vet8hxy4/15/) to show you how you can do

```
.directive("myTooltip", [ function(){
return{
scope: {
customers:'=myTooltip'
},
link:function(scope, el){
var toDisplay = '';
for(var i = 0; i < scope.customers.length; i++){
toDisplay += scope.customers[i].name+'\n';
}

el.attr('title', toDisplay);
```

Comment: @klent you will have to use like this in your html `<div  my-tooltip="customersList">hover me</div>`